# How to add event for Checkbox click in Asp.net Gridview Column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview in asp where i have added first column as checkbox column.Now i want to select this column and get the id values of the row ..But I am not getting how to do it..

This is my Aspx code..

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="LightGoldenrodYellow" 
                    BorderColor="Tan" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="2" ForeColor="Black" 
                    GridLines="None">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" />
                    <Columns>
                     <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkhdr" runat="server" />
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                          <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkChild" runat="server" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Username">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("col0") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Role(Admin)">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAdmin" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("col1") %>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Role(User)">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkUser" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("col2") %>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Role(GeneralUser)">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkgen" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("col3") %>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

And here is my code behind file...

```
protected void BindGridviewData()
{

    var role = from MembershipUser u in Membership.GetAllUsers()
                select new
                {
                    User = u.UserName,
                    Role = string.Join(",", Roles.GetRolesForUser(u.UserName))
                };

    DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
    dTable.Columns.Add("col0", typeof(string));
    dTable.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(bool));
    dTable.Columns.Add("col2", typeof(bool));
    dTable.Columns.Add("col3", typeof(bool));
    foreach (MembershipUser u in Membership.GetAllUsers())
    {
        DataRow dRow = dTable.NewRow();
        dRow[0] = u.UserName;

        string[] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(u.UserName);
        dRow[1] = roles.Contains("Admin") ? true : false;
        dRow[2] = roles.Contains("DPAO User") ? true : false;
        dRow[3] = roles.Contains("GeneralUser") ? true : false;
        dTable.Rows.Add(dRow);
    }
    GridView1.DataSource = dTable;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Please Guys help me as i have no idea how to accomplish this ...Thanks in advance...

Comment: I've done quiet the same thing last month but I used the Telerik RadGridView, which offers the property _SelectedItem_. I don't know if its available in asp grid. If so, just add `SelectedItem="{Binding id, Mode=TwoWay}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want **Delete** record by **Button** try this:

Add a Button outside of gridview for Delete:

```
<asp:Button ID="cmdDelete" runat="server" onclick="cmdDelete_Click" Text="Delete" />
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindGridviewData();
    }
}
protected void BindGridviewData()
{
    DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
    dTable.Columns.Add("col0", typeof(string));
    dTable.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(bool));
    dTable.Columns.Add("col2", typeof(bool));
    dTable.Columns.Add("col3", typeof(bool));
    foreach (MembershipUser u in Membership.GetAllUsers())
    {
        DataRow dRow = dTable.NewRow();
        dRow[0] = u.UserName;
        string[] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(u.UserName);
        dRow[1] = roles.Contains("Admin") ? true : false;
        dRow[2] = roles.Contains("DPAO User") ? true : false;
        dRow[3] = roles.Contains("GeneralUser") ? true : false;
        dTable.Rows.Add(dRow);
    }
    GridView1.DataSource = dTable;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
protected void cmdDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkChild");
        if (chk.Checked)
        {
            Label username = (Label)row.FindControl("Label1");
            Membership.DeleteUser(username.Text);
            BindGridviewData();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

try this,

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:CheckBox ID="chkview" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkview_CheckedChanged" />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

add checkbox change event in aspx.cs page

```
protected void chkview_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = ((GridViewRow)((CheckBox)sender).NamingContainer);
    int index = row.RowIndex;
    CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox)Gridview.Rows[index].FindControl("chkview");
    string yourvalue = cb1.Text;
    //here you can find your control and get value(Id).

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`OnCheckedChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.oncheckedchanged.aspx) event

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:CheckBox ID="chkgen" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("col3") %>'  
        OnCheckedChanged="chkgen_OnCheckedChanged"/>
</ItemTemplate>
```

CS:

```
protected void chkgen_OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      int selRowIndex = ((GridViewRow)(((CheckBox)sender).Parent.Parent)).RowIndex;
      CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gridView.Rows[selRowIndex].FindControl("chkgen");

      if (cb.Checked)
      {
             //Perform your logic
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through gridivew row collection and check whether it has been selected.

Add selected row (or get ID in your case) and do further processing.

Below URL may help you to get started:

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/GridView-with-CheckBox-Get-Selected-Rows-in-ASPNet.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void GetFillDropdown()
    {
        string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SheetalAcademy"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(consString);

        int EID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["EmailID"].ToString());
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select id,Course_Name from tbl_Courses where EID='" + EID + "' and Active='True'", conn);
        conn.Open();
        ddCourseType.Items.Clear();
        ddCourseType.Items.Add("All");
        ddCourseType.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
        ddCourseType.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        ddCourseType.DataTextField = "Course_Name";
        ddCourseType.DataValueField = "id";
        ddCourseType.DataBind();
        conn.Close();

    }
```