# Selection of checkboxes lost during pagination of gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a problem in gridview, as per requirement i have set No of Records per page = 4 in gridview. I have to select Checkbox against every complaint but problem is then when i got to next pge in gridview and e.g fro 1 to 2 then when i come back to page 1 then it doesn't show TICK in check boxes . It doesn't remember my selection when i browse to and back to page.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewSmsComplaints" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="4" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="mGrid" BorderColor="#333333"  Width="550px" OnPageIndexChanging="GridViewSmsComplaints_PageIndexChanging" >
               <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="ID" /> 
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Recieving Date" DataField="RecievingDate" />  
                <%--<asp:BoundField HeaderText="ToMobileNo" DataField="ToMobileNo" />  --%>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="FromMobileNo" DataField="FromMobileNo" /> 
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Message" DataField="Message" >   
                   <ItemStyle Wrap="True" />
                   </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IsComplaint">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:CheckBox ID="ckboxIsComplaint"  runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsComplaint").ToString()) %>' />
                 </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
               </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Once the user has checked/unchecked the box, you need to update the underlying database column

Comment: that takes resources and post backs, some other ways ?

Comment: Have a look here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18909579/how-to-add-event-for-checkbox-click-in-asp-net-gridview-column

Answer (score 1):

please check the above link.here your problem was clearly explained **[here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31849/Maintaining-States-of-Selected-CheckBoxes-in-Diffe)**.i think so it may be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

As per comments...

If you do not update the underlying database by processing the `OnCheckChanged` event of the check box, then it will simply be reading the same data all the time.

From [How to add event for Checkbox click in Asp.net Gridview Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18909579/how-to-add-event-for-checkbox-click-in-asp-net-gridview-column), I have **extracted** the required information and tried to modify to fit your initial question.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IsComplaint">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:CheckBox ID="ckboxIsComplaint"  runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsComplaint").ToString()) %>' OnCheckedChanged="chk_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true/>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

add checkbox change event in aspx.cs page

```
protected void chk_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = ((GridViewRow)((CheckBox)sender).NamingContainer);
    <your data source>.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["B"] = ((CheckBox)GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[row.RowIndex].FindControl("ckboxIsComplaint")).Checked;
```

}